# SQlite3, Trying to insert values from user input into DB browser db using placeholders with a field that is autoincrement

Tags: python, database, sqlite, pyqt6, user-registration

I'm trying to insert values into my db for the MyAccount table using placeholders. I think the issue lies in the fact that I have a field that is autoincrement and so I am not referencing it.
I keep getting different errors, such as database data type mismatch which i think is for the autoincrement field that has no input for it (accountID) and it's just not working and I have tried to look up so many different variations. Any help?

[image: db]
[image]
I tried this, I was expecting the values to insert into the db

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image, post it as a code block.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to call `execute` like (e.g.)

```
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(
    'INSERT INTO MyAccount (fullName, username, password, school, phoneNumber, yearGroup) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
    (input_fullName, input_username, input_password, input_school, input_phoneNumber, input_yearGroup),
)
con.commit()
```

, that is

- the query as a string with ? placeholders (and I've here spelled out the column names so the placeholders' order doesn't matter)
- the placeholders' values as a single tuple

This (and the alternative dictionary method) is documented in [the sqlite3 module's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/sqlite3.html#how-to-use-placeholders-to-bind-values-in-sql-queries).

Comment: Thanks, it still does not seem to work, with a tuple

Comment: "still does not seem to work" – what happens? What doesn't?

Comment: Error in saving to database Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 6, and there are 0 supplied

Comment: Are you _sure_ you're passing that second argument to `cur.execute()` then?

Answer (score 0):

As AKX mentioned you have to pass the parameters by tuple or list. Here's a short example for a function:

```
def qry_exec(db, sql, parameters):
    qry = QSqlQuery (db)
    qry.prepare (sql)
    for value in parameters:
       qry.addBindValue (value)
    if not qry.exec_ ():
        print (qry.lastError ().text ())
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

You can call it by:

```
    sql = "INSERT INTO dbtable (field1, field2, field3) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?)"
    ret = QtSqlTools.qry_exec (db, sql, [ data1, data2, data3])
```

where db is an open database